# Nginx постоянно редиректит домен на https (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

Всем привет. Когда пытаюсь зайти на сайт https://example.com/ то меня редиректит постоянно на https://example.com/
Но а когда пытаюсь зайти в https://example.com/example-page/ то всё окей открываются.
Именно страница https://example.com/ не работает с причиной ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (301 Moved Permanently)

Мой конфиг:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bpm.eman.uz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bpm.eman.uz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
        location /{
            proxy_pass http://192.168.183.20:86/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что редиректит именно nginx, а не этот ваш 192.168.183.21:84? Вы уверены, что редиректит именно этот конфиг? Если стереть его, редирект пропадает?

Comment: И ещё, вы уверены что этот редирект не закешировался в браузере?

Comment: Здравствуйте, да уверен, проверил даже с нескольких компьютеров и телефона. Именно example.com тупо редиректит без остановки а остальные страницы норм

Comment: Тогда актуален мой первый комментарий

Comment: да уверен, для примера написал ip и порт другого рабочего сайта.

Comment: Мой внешний ip http://213.230.66.181:86/ как вы можете увидеть тут всё окей. И дело точно в nginx конфигурации (по моему мнению)

Comment: обновил (конфиг)

Comment: Адрес `https://bpm.eman.uz` присылает редирект 301 на адрес `http://bpm.eman.uz`, ничего подобного показанный nginx-конфиг делать не может

Comment: Зато по сертификату видно, что перед nginx стоит ещё один сервер — Cloudflare. Вы уверены, что Cloudflare присылает к вашему nginx https-запросы вообще? Если вы настроили его на использование только http, то вполне логично, что https-секция конфига полностью игнорируется

Comment: аа да вы правы, но дело в том что основной домен на другом сервере, а поддомен не работает на сертификате от Cloudflare поэтому я отключил ssl на cloudflare, не подскажете пожалуйста как быть? (upd) в cloudflare я отключил SSL и Automatic HTTPS Rewrites через Page Rules

Comment: ляя я поменял ssl off на ssl flexible всё заработало. Огромное вам спасибо andreymal напишите как ответ я отмечу вас! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: А лучше бы предпринять что-нибудь, чтобы заработал «Full (strict)» (а наличие конфига от letsencrypt намекает, что он и так должен работать)

Comment: Напишите ниже ответ пожалуйста, хотелось бы ваш ответ отметить :) Ещё раз большое спасибо вам